# From a shortcode I want to pass a value to display a different page

Tags: shortcode

I have a page with a shortcode that displays a dropdown. I just can't figure out how to return that value to a function/page to show the resulting information. The second page would take that value and show a list. I've tried everything I can think of. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Sample code would be wonderful. Thank you,

Comment: Thank you. That was so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways this can be done. Here is one rudimentary version of doing this using the `GET` method and two different shortcodes for the two pages. You have to place the code in your theme's `functions.php` and to create two different pages and place `[first-page]` shortcode on the first page, and `[second-page]` shortcode on the second page and use the form on the first page.

```
<?php

/**
 * Shortcode for the First page.
 * 
 * Show form on the first page to grab information.
 */
function wpse380676_first_page_shortcode() {
    $second_page_id = 1832;

    ob_start();
    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo get_the_permalink($second_page_id) ?>" method="GET">
        <label><input type="radio" name="question" value="yes"> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="question" value="no"> No</label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'first-page', 'wpse380676_first_page_shortcode' );

/**
 * Shortcode for the Second page.
 * 
 * Handle data from the previous page and do something.
 */
function wpse380676_second_page_shortcode() {
    $question = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'question', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if (!$question) {
        return;
    }

    if ('yes' === $question) {
        echo 'The answer is Yes';
    } else {
        echo 'The answer is No';
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'second-page', 'wpse380676_second_page_shortcode' );
```

Tested in WordPress 5.6 with the default theme 'Twenty Twenty One'